# How can I change Layout Editor Preview Pane ToolBar menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I didn't understand how, but the main toolbar of the preview pane in the layout editor of Android Studio has changed :

It used to look like this :
[image: Previsou toolbar]

But now it changed into this :

[image: Actual toolbar]

I tried to reset configuration, and even reinstall completely Android Studio but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea about how I could revert change ? Thank you in advance

I am using Android Studio 2.2 with Ubuntu 16.04 amd64.

Comment: Why do you want to revert? All the same buttons plus some are there

Comment: It is because it takes more space on the screen, and it reduce the space for the files tabs

Comment: which files tab? You mean the palette?

Comment: I mean, the filenames tabs, such as "Activity.java", "activity_main.xml"... That's why I would like to reverse this behaviour

Comment: In fact, I realized that was really a huge problem, I finally got used to this...

Answer (score 0):

well in this case you could always hide the Palette and Properties tab ,unfortunately i don't think there is any way to customize this tool bar.
Although you could use Android Studio version 2.1 .